# Is it possible to map multiple categories of a VisualMap to multiple data values in a sunburst diagramm?

Tags: echarts

is it possible with a "piecewise" VisualMap (Apache E-Charts), to map multiple categories to multiple data values in a sunburst diagram?

As of now and as I understand, you can have a piecewise VisualMap and you map one category to exactly one data value.

I'm looking for a way to have the following:

| Theme | Value |
| --- | --- |
| TH-A | CAT-1, CAT-2 |
| TH-B | CAT-2, CAT-3 |
| TH-C | CAT-1, CAT-3 |
| TH-D | CAT-1, CAT-2 |
| TH-E | CAT-3 |

Here is a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/xv4so7ne/14/

So if I select (as examples):

- **CAT-1** the sunburst diagram should highlight **TH-A, TH-C, TH-D**
- **CAT-1, CAT-3** the sunburst diagram should highlight **TH-A, TH-B, TH-C, TH-E**
- **CAT-3** the sunburst diagram should highlight **TH-B, TH-C, TH-E**

Is this possible with this diagramy type, to select multiple categories and highlight multiple pieces?

At the moment we have `values: [value]` to map the VisualMap. For this I'm searching for `values: [[CAT-1,CAT-3]]` to get correctly mapped.

Best,
Ronny

Comment: I am not really sure what kind of visual representation you want to achieve. Echarts sunburst series highlight all children by default. If you want to change the color of specific data items on hover you can do so manually by using [event callbacks](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events.mouseover) and [setOption](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption).

Comment: My idea is to use the VisualMap (piecewise "category") as an additional highlighting option in that sense, that I can select zero, one or more categories (eg. CAT-1,CAT-2,CAT-3) and with this selection in the VisualMap, the parts in the chart are highlighted. But this would mean, that I have to be able to assign a part (or piece in the chart) of that series a value like ["CAT-1", "CAT-2"] instead of only a numerical value. Is it more clear want I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification from your comment I do understand what you want to achieve and this is not possible using a visaulMap.

But you can do so by using an invisable helper series which will be used to populate the legend and the [legendselectchanged](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.legendselectchanged) event to modify the sunburst data via [setOption](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.getOption).

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sunburst-simple&code=G4QwTgBAJiAuIQLwQNoCgIQN4cxAdiALYCmAXBAOQDiYI-UADiJQDS6YDGcFl3sEAIxsOETgAsAlgBsoYEvgro8eHCpWFSvAKr5O0khAAyJAPYj1efr34QAzBcsRQ0gK7khAVnZOxU2fKKqKKWar54mh6UAMKmrgDOkvgQAFIgnADWjuFiPFS2wj45ziBuHgBMIeoAvkW-YTmRvLEJSRAAsuAAntnh1vlwEOW9vi7uFN5VlhIycgpKU04NxZhNVGmZ8ab4I8X9fIPDdSslZRSVJxDViyoAujdXx6EPq8RRLYnJAEIKu9N5BwEhRep3GEAALA9rr57pZalVlho3rwAGJwcQkMB_XKwGyHbFjDyCAAMTys_jmQWU4URTjWlHaJGxKn2tgcZMshImUI5qhB9K-YFMsAxkAACiRYJjmVYAQUZZguUIoYtYTVRGr4ZhlvSAHL0Tg9Y6s_HGimBBbPXz03T6Qy6yQZJm8k0CdmLGYBebBHK0yz0j5tH6wWBGkGuoYK0FEnkPP3qANxT6pBT4MMrCPulZKi7haFONUqfOYTVoW4AbjQVdMjFgkm2SGwuAMAHMFFAKMt4uJTAB3CiwMDuY6SKVEADKoYMnc4pmkpjAvGkkhb4lgACMypQtXgYPAlFh6fLatgj_iT4fkQM3dvbkUd_FMZISPFLXzLKHGFF4q58OvXGA8SwLse4gBQoHHDu2pVJ-USMM-ux0FAkgJEopLEneVSJAY-C4hAg7DlUoEHmeQLbqwp5XoCkYXqR9i3qIO73NUlZVkQXTROI4CwAAdNsAAUlCtu2j4GJwsASPQbZQGwEAAGa_uJ9b4PxzB0EQ8QAJRNlw2xARAokkOJJBQI2anEPEPGGcZUCVpgRDgBkAAicAgPx1lSlAmmVtUmlVmgCl6HWDYOWAzmue5JBiZ52lhAYAj4CQAAesAmMAUWNqBdkQL2_iGPxiUpWlUU8ThLYihAACEiDIMSsWiLO-D6ZwAGBKlJDpdIjaFe1nXZasyW9RlyAoBWohyQuED8Y1-mjiQRAQKYcliK1ChDdI9WWJIy2RdFJkoHNRA8fwtybU4h0oJQh2Tl0BiULcjZYLO86LlQ8gySxVTVBAUWPjp51jpd11TkyD3IL-UAkHJSQmf1eDFngVTbVNh3HeaChnf6g3FV1yA9Tjx3bPw_Go56lLeV9jG4PmuDsZx3FWZKADytbKfxWCPmAz6vqgWDEdArnVLcvloNUQA):

```js
option = {
  legend: {
    show: true,
    itemStyle: {color: 'lightblue'},
    data: [{name: 'cat 1'}, {name: 'cat 2'}, {name: 'cat 3'}],
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'sunburst',
      data: data,
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: [0,0],
      silent: true,
      data: [{name: 'cat 1'}, {name: 'cat 2'}, {name: 'cat 3'}]
    },
  ]
};


myChart.on('legendselectchanged', function(params) {
  const selected = params.selected;
  markData(selected);
})


function markData(selected) {
  let nextLevel = data;
  while (nextLevel.length !== 0) {
    const currentLevel = nextLevel;
    nextLevel = [];
    for (const item of currentLevel) {
      if (selected[item.cat]) {
        item['itemStyle'] = {color: 'red'};
      } else {
        item['itemStyle'] = undefined;
      }
      
      if (item.children) {
        nextLevel = nextLevel.concat(item.children);
      }
    }
  }
  
  myChart.setOption({series: [{data: data}]})
}


var data = [
  {
    name: 'Grandpa',
    cat: 'cat 1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Uncle Leo',
        cat: 'cat 3',
        value: 15,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Cousin Jack',
            cat: 'cat 1',
            value: 2
          },
          {
            name: 'Cousin Mary',
            cat: 'cat 2',
            value: 5,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'Jackson',
                cat: 'cat 2',
                value: 2
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'Cousin Ben',
            cat: 'cat 1',
            value: 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Father',
        cat: 'cat 2',
        value: 10,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Me',
            cat: 'cat 3',
            value: 5
          },
          {
            name: 'Brother Peter',
            cat: 'cat 1',
            value: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Nancy',
    cat: 'cat 2',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Uncle Nike',
        cat: 'cat 3',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Cousin Betty',
            cat: 'cat 2',
            value: 1
          },
          {
            name: 'Cousin Jenny',
            cat: 'cat 3',
            value: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Note, that you can achieve similar effects using a helper visualMap (with seriesIndex set to one that is not present) and the [datarangeselected](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.datarangeselected) event if you want to use the legend.

Comment: Oh this looks great, thank you for your tips and ideas!

Comment: Hey, I have an additional question, maybe you can give me a hint. Clicking on a child item in the sunburst diagram will "zoom" into the sunburst. Now clicking on a category from the legend will "reset" to chart and it is displayed from to root level. It's through setting the complete data again in the markData function. Do you know how can I prevent this and only update to color of the items of the current level?

Comment: If the zooming in is not neccessary you can disable it with `nodeClick: false`. Otherwise you can maybe use [highlight](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.highlight) or [select](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.select) actions instead of `setOption`

Comment: the zooming is neccessary for me, it seems if the data is updated by the _setOption_ function call, then the [optionUpdated](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/031a908fafaa57e2277b2f720087195925ec38cf/src/chart/sunburst/SunburstSeries.ts#L200) is triggered, which resets the rootView, but I don't found a way yet to prevent this ...

Comment: yeah I dont think there is some out of the box solution for that sadly. (highlights dont seem to persist the zooming either). So the only possibility I can currently think of is to exchange the sunburst by the child which was clicked on in setOption, similar to the way i suggested [here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19362)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which purpose your visual representation should have you might be better off using multiple [pie series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie) together with [mouse events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events.mouseover) and [highlight actions](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.highlight) or [setOption](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption) to manually configure what should be highlighted.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWzQCGAtlsQOQCCAxuwRrAGI7B6zADRUKYAJ4gmsZiHwix6bABss7MFgAmAWWBaZzDBGgBzNYuroctLRACuRUgAZhsgMzOApMwC6oq1gVWgAjLBViVED0EGBjSBgWE2hcS2iAMxgwAGUIAC8ZAEYAFiVYAF8Aqy1aMFpiMmjkWAA3WhV7IoBWYoAONzpGFmysWhx2AAtYAFEzEyxmCqrApFb2zuIAdk2ugYZDABEIHHUwRcqy9FW2jpkANk2ATj2h2R0xgGssSDMRTHDTtpiGAcJ0KmVfGILtQolZBoYOFwMDx-II0tRJNIWPIFssKDY7I4Gsx3F0fG5mHdvH48egIJp6NlJGpIpdYKBaOx6RJiM4AHSbMrQqxYeggCa0YxOWGBemipkSFnIDlcyTEQpuELAHAGHAAdQgWjAE2IACZNdrdQBhYAqbUsE5aZjlIW02A1OoNNnXdZFZx9F6GABCtEN9nObqua1uxHcpMDLCOJw0Ee90Y2sHchVcNH2LGm9FDKlTTR9Mdgpq6Gtzr2YAHFgMBzAslmmbhnTe5ignZABVaBQOCsLQYEvRMsZkqbHvMIMmUxjlbporxmuGABqhqwwFgw9HrdLy_VznNa5YAHljbh9y7ApDqLfYJDygBuFAoegSK0SnBgPkwAAKZh6GARxtxaVI3HSexoA0QcAJAMYGAwABKSg6XSWAEKQ-gMD5bA8AIABJaADAAD1gABCeBEGcNCTjAewcGgN90HID1aBI8iEFgRCbFwvkOK4rAyNY2AIEwgChNIkSEBo2A6PQihpO4xASFcDVzXcXwxPKWBwmwcTJJU2SaMQQo0Jld1ak4mSKLU9xhG7LodPIPSDKwJT0BM-zSF2O5hE2Vz0EfT9vzGP87AwRCwEmDgEmgACrMxQwJggUwJhUdKJjOPECPwDAADk81kRFuD4AQhDxHziB8qpyhQt8GrfD8vx_P9AOA0DsFA3LYGg2CEuw_jUKUiSsL45D8NwArhIo6jaPo74mJY8hyDC9rBIgaLajiuDAOSqRDC0YAAHdoBAYIJHRf5CIwOaGg0_wxBqlxhE04RHOc4QAqCtzGpQZqgA):

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      selectedMode: 'single',
      radius: [0, '30%'],
      label: {
        position: 'inner',
        fontSize: 14
      },
      data: [
        { value: 1548, name: 'Search Engine' },
        { value: 775, name: 'Direct' },
        { value: 679, name: 'Marketing', selected: true }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['35%', '60%'],
      itemStyle: {
        opacity: 0.7
      },
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {opacity: 1, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red'}
      },
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: 'Baidu' },
        { value: 335, name: 'Direct' },
        { value: 310, name: 'Email' },
        { value: 251, name: 'Google' },
        { value: 234, name: 'Union Ads' },
        { value: 147, name: 'Bing' },
        { value: 135, name: 'Video Ads' },
        { value: 102, name: 'Others' }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

myChart.on('mouseover', function(params) {
  if (params.seriesIndex !== 0) return;
  
  dataIndex = params.dataIndex;
  if (dataIndex === 0) {
    dataIndex = [0,1,2,3];
  } else if (dataIndex === 1) {
    dataIndex = [3,4,5];
  } else {
    dataIndex = [5,6,7];
  }
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'highlight',
    seriesName: 'Access From',
    dataIndex: dataIndex,
  });
});

myChart.on('mouseout', function(params) {
  if (params.seriesIndex !== 0) return;
  
  myChart.dispatchAction({
    type: 'downplay',
    seriesIndex: [0,1],
    dataIndex: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
  });
});
```